# How is measure able to filter dimension via fact table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables: dimProduct and factSales

Dim table has productid, name, category

Fact table has salesid, productid, status, amount, paiddate

I have a table visual that shows the status from the fact table. Against each status I want to show the count of products and the count of distinct category.

CountProducts=DISTINCTCOUNT(FACTSALES[PRODUCTID])

CountDistinctCategory=DISTINCTCOUNT(dimProduct[category])

How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the cross-filter direction for your relationship to 'Both', so that filtering can also propagate from the fact table to the dimension table.

Alternatively, using DAX:

```
CountDistinctCategory =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT( dimProduct[category] ),
    TREATAS(
        VALUES( factSales[productid] ),
        dimProduct[productid]
    )
)
```

Comment: This question is about Dax calculation

Comment: You should make that clearer in your question. Have amended my post.